# Spring webflux - continous emitter

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

So I have a simple method

```
Flux<Task> getTaskToProcess();
```

I would like my system to stream entites continously. Right now I achive it in old fashion like

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
    getTaskToProcess().flatMap(....)
}
```

I am pretty sure it's not the best way by reactive approach. How to achieve continous emitter in project reactor ?

Comment: any task you put on a mono/flux will emit as soon as the task is done resolving.

Comment: yes I do understand I was looking for something like inifinite scheduler - so while(true) loop i reactive manner

Comment: You can take a look `repeat` method: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#repeat--

Answer (score 0):

Try Flux#create or Flux# generate:

```java
Flux<Task> tasks = Flux.create(sink -> {
  while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     sink.next(something);
  }
  sink.complete();
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newSingle("stdin publisher"))
```